# How to timeout Javamail POP3 when the TCP connection is made but OK not received

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

```
Session l_session = Session.getDefaultInstance(l_props);
final Store l_store = l_session.getStore(l_protocol);
l_store.connect(a_req.getServer(), a_req.getPort(), a_req.getUsername(), a_req.getPassword());
```

The TCP connection to the POP3 server is made, but the first "OK" from the server is never received.  I would like some sort of timeout exception, but the program just waits forever.  Debug output looks like

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsy stems, Inc]
DEBUG POP3: connecting to host "localhost", port 9898, isSSL false
```

I've set mail.pop3.timeout and mail.pop3.connectiontimeout to reasonable values, but no timeout is ever thrown.  How can I cause it to timeout in this situation?

I have a VERY crude workaround that uses a ConnectionListener attached to the Store and sets a flag when the connection is made (which appears to be after the initial OK and credentials) and a separate watcher thread.  The close() method on Store seems to be synchronized() so I call a System.exit(1) when I detect that it has been too long.

I use linux command "nc -l 9898" to simulate the POP3 server that never answers with "OK".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance; read the javadocs for the difference - your property settings could be getting ignored.

You're using a relatively old version of JavaMail so you could try upgrading to see if that helps.  The mail.pop3.timeout property should do it.